# dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Tags: python-3.x, flask, heroku

I am deploying a Python API using FLASK on Heroku. It is deployed successfully but getting an error while opening the webpage.

main.py ->

```
    from flask import Flask
    from flask import request

    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/',methods=['GET'])
    def validation_page():
        name = str(request.args['name'])
        return name


    if __name__ == '__main__':
      app.run(debug=True)
```

Procfile ->

```
    web: gunicorn app:main
```

Opening the web page with this URL -> https://test-app-validate.herokuapp.com/?name=deepak

Logs ->

```
    heroku logs --tail

    2021-02-20T09:27:04.943561+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET 
    path="/?name=deepak" host=test-app-validate.herokuapp.com request_id=38dc080a-87a3-4b4f-8d28- 
    ba891041b141 fwd="183.83.42.60" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2021-02-20T09:27:05.572264+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET 
    path="/favicon.ico" host=test-app-validate.herokuapp.com request_id=90d6e83d-6488-44ec-a7d2- 
    3a01188f3fdc fwd="183.83.42.60" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Tried :-

```
    heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Please tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: See this, it might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/61331665/9095551

Answer (score 2):

The [format](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/run.html#gunicorn) is `<module>:<callable>`. In your case, you've pointed Gunicorn at the module `app` and the callable `main`, which is the other way around — you have a module named `main` and a callable named `app`.

Your Procfile should say `web: gunicorn main:app`.